# Trouble with UIStackView

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview

I watched through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0llR7sfrkc) to learn about `UIStackView` but I'm still having trouble. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ATI.png) is what I'm working with right now. The bottom half (which is partly covered by the date picker) is what I'm looking to achieve.

Three horizontal views in one row and three vertical views below it. As you can see from my stackview hierarchy, the white background view and orange background view are in a vertical stack. I didn't touch the view with a white background to show the contrast of what is happening.

- Months, days, weeks are in a horizontal stack.
- Seconds, minutes, hours are in a vertical stack.
- Then those two stacks are in a vertical stack.

That vertical stack is pinned 20 pixels in every direction.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the rendered result so wonky?

Thanks!

Comment: In your view hierarchy, why is there a view between the topmost stackview and the one underneath it? I suspect you don't have constraints set up properly between the plain view and the stackview right inside of it.

Comment: @JohnGibb I'm confused as to which view your questioning about when you say "and the one underneath it". What is the "one" that your referring to? I'm pretty sure it's the orange background view.